# Change default crontab editor to nano in FreeBSD

Tags: cron, freebsd, vi, linux

When I edit the crontab using `crontab -e` it opens the crontab in vi. I'd prefer it to use nano. How can I change this?

EDIT:

For some reason the `export` command returns `command not found`. And changing the EDITOR env value didn't work for `crontab -e`.

The following command worked on my system:

`setenv VISUAL /usr/local/bin/nano`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For sh based shells:

```
export EDITOR=/path/to/nano
```

For C shell based:

```
setenv EDITOR /path/to/nano
```

Remember that unless you save these setting to your login profile script (/home/user/.bash_profile for example), you lose the setting at log out.

If I remember correctly, FreeBSD uses C shell as the default user shell.

Comment: As a note, csh uses ~/.cshrc for the profile script, so you'd need to put the setenv command in there.

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
export EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano
```

adjust for your location of nano (use 'which' to find).  You can put that command in your .bashrc or similar profile script to have it in effect all the time.

Answer (score -1):

Probably by setting the environment variable EDITOR.

I.e.

```
export EDITOR=/path/to/nano
```

Answer (score -3):

There is a symbolic link under */etc/alternatives/editor* that can be pointed to /path/to/nano

You can use the **update-alternatives** utility to do this as well - although I am not too familiar with using it.

(note - I'm speaking from an 'ubuntu' point-of-view.  not sure if this is the same for FreeBSD)

Comment: It's not the same for FreeBSD.